# Java jigsaw module app: Throws java.lang.module.ResolutionException, spuriously claims split package

Tags: java, java-module, java-platform-module-system

I have a little example main class depending on modules myproject.base and myproject.desktop, which depends on myproject.base. There's also a number of other myproject.* modules, and the example app (also inside a jigsaw module) explicitly depends on all of them. Everything compiles fine, but at runtime I get this error:

```
Error occurred during initialization of boot layer
java.lang.module.ResolutionException: Module myproject.desktop contains package org.myproject.util, module myproject.base exports package org.myproject.util to myproject.desktop
```

This seems to indicate a split package org.myproject.util between the aforementioned modules, however that is *not* the case. It only exists within myproject.base, from where it is indeed exported, and it is used within myproject.desktop.
Am I mis-interpreting the error message? Could there be an underlying misconfiguration that produces the error spuriously?

The error appears when using either openjdk 10.0.2 or 11-ea+26

Best,
andi

Comment: Care to share the `module-info.java` of the `myproject.base`, `myproject.desktop` and your current application?

Comment: Are you 110% sure that myproject.desktop doesn't contain any classes or resources in the org.myproject.util package? I would check the output directory (or the JAR contents) in case there are some residual files that should not be there.